# How can I get the Unix timestamp in a file?

Tags: python

My goal is to write a script which will once I run it write the current Unix timestamp to a file. I tried several scripts which show the Unix timestamp directly such as this:

```
import time
print time.time()
```

While searching for an answer I came across a script which will write the current date and time with the datetime module to a file:

```
import datetime
f=open("/home/user/file.txt",'a')
f.write(datetime.datetime.now().ctime())
```

So I thought that if it's possible to write it with
`(datetime.datetime.now().ctime()`, the same would be possible with for example:

```
import time
f=open("/home/user/file.txt",'a')
f.write(time.time())
```

Unfortunately I got this same error every time I tried something similar:`TypeError: expected a string or other character buffer object`. I've tried fixing this, but I couldn't so far. Any help or recommendation is greately appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get file creation & modification date/times in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237079/how-to-get-file-creation-modification-date-times-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Message is meaning: `f.write` requires a `string` typed data. `time.time()` returns a `float` that you have to cast into string.

```
import time
f=open("/home/ssh-jump/file.txt",'a')
f.write('%f' % time.time())
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to convert your output to string, eg:

`f.write(str(time.time()))`